# get the inheritance of an element in the XML using python

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, large-data

[Please look at the picture for reference example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHtRR.jpg)I have a large complex XML structure and I need to find the inheritance of specific elements when I type in the element name. I need Python code to do this.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def find_inheritance(element_name, xml_file):
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

    elements = set()
    for elem in root.iter():
        if elem.tag == element_name:
            # add the current element to the set
            elements.add(elem.tag)
    
            # traverse the parent elements and add them to the set
            parent = elem.get('parent')
            while parent is not None:
                elements.add(parent)
                parent = root.find(f".//*[@id='{parent}']")\
                    .get('parent', None)
    
    return elements

# get user input

element_name = input("Enter the name of the XML element: ")
xml_file = input("Enter the path of the XML file: ")

# find inheritance elements

inheritance_elements = find_inheritance(element_name, xml_file)

# print the result

print(f"Inheritance elements of {element_name}: {inheritance_elements}")
```

I am getting the output as:

> Inheritance of element name: set ()

Comment: Please edit your question to include a small XML file that could be used to demonstrate the problem. I appreciate you have a large complex XML file, but it should be possible for you to make up a smaller one for the purposes of this question. Please also include in your question what output you would expect your script to generate when run on this file.

Comment: I added a picture of how I wanted the output to look. Please look into it

Comment: Please post input xml example as @Luke Woodward mentioned it,please.

Comment: Please include the XML in your question as text, not as an image. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors for reasons why we don't accept images of code, data or errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your image (which, by the way, is [bad practice](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); you should include that content in the text/body of your question), you say:

> `"When I Input the id =212, it should be able to print all its inherited values. I.e., <Grandchild>, <Child>, <Parent> and <root>"`

which I take to mean that you want to input an `id`. I've reworked your `find_inheritance()` function below to use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) instead of Python's [built-in `xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html), which has a [largely compatible API, but is preferable for a variety of reasons](https://lxml.de/compatibility.html). One such reason is the existence of an `Element.iterancestors()` method that makes this task much simpler.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET

def find_inheritance(element_id: "int|str", xml_file: str) -> list:
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    
    target_elem = tree.find(f".//*[@id='{element_id}']") # find element with an `id` attribute matching the input `element_id`
    ancestry = [ancestor.tag for ancestor in target_elem.iterancestors()] # use `iterancestors()` to iterate over the element's ancestors; make a list of their tags
    
    return [target_elem.tag] + ancestry
```

Given a file called `example.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <parent id="1" name="Parent 1">
        <child id="11" name="Child 1.1">
            <grandchild id="111" name="Grandchild 1.1.1" />
            <grandchild id="112" name="Grandchild 1.1.2" />
        </child>
        <child id="12" name="Child 1.2">
            <grandchild id="121" name="Grandchild 1.2.1" />
            <grandchild id="122" name="Grandchild 1.2.2" />
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent id="2" name="Parent 2">
        <child id="21" name="Child 2.1">
            <grandchild id="211" name="Grandchild 2.1.1" />
            <grandchild id="212" name="Grandchild 2.1.2" />
        </child>
        <child id="22" name="Child 2.2">
            <grandchild id="221" name="Grandchild 2.2.1" />
            <grandchild id="222" name="Grandchild 2.2.2" />
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Calling `find_inheritance(212, "example.xml")` will produce the following output:

```
['grandchild', 'child', 'parent', 'root']
```

You could remove the `.tag` in the list comprehensions if you wanted the `Element` objects themselves, or change it to `.get("name")` if you wanted the values of the `name` attributes. Not that this returns a `list`, not a `set`, as it seems the order of the elements (which `set`s do not preserve) is meaningful here.